# Doesn't it need to be changed into 'when our story starts from'?

Tags: grammaticality

> When Mr. and Mrs. Dursley woke up on the dull, gray Tuesday **our story
>   starts**, there was nothing about the cloudy sky outside to suggest that
>   strange and mysterious things would soon be happening all over the
>   country. (Harry Potter)

I’m wondering if ‘our story starts’ needs to be changed, from a grammatical aspect, into ‘when our story starts from.’ Would you let me know what am I thinking wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A story starts *on* a day, not *from* it.

   (But it would ***run** from* a starting time *to* an ending time.)
2. Accordingly you want *Tuesday on which our story starts*. But *on which* may be replaced by *when*; and in such cases *when* is in effect a WH- relative pronoun, not a relative adverb.

   Consequently, it may (like *who* or *whom* or *which*) be omitted (indicated below by the sign *Ø*)

> ....the dull, gray Tuesday *Ø / when / on which* our story starts ...

Answer (score 4):

*Our story starts* is a relative clause, but the relative pronoun is omitted. The reader has to insert *on which* (or *when*).